# machine learning/ deep learning model python

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I have made a deep learning model for predicting the real estate prices based on different parameters such as: area, number of rooms, floor, number of floors, age of the building, type of building, etc.

My dataset is scrapped, data is prepared to analysis (discrete columns as dummies itp). My model is shown in the following code. The problem is that the model's accuracy is always 0.

Here is my code:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=6, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=6, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 32, epochs = 100)

accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

I couldn't find tutorial for similar case.

Comment: Providing a minimal reproducible example would be helpful. Regardless, just by looking at the code, it seems like that wrong loss (`binary_crossentropy`) and activation (`sigmoid`) are used. For a regression problem, an appropriate loss, e.g. mse, mae, msle, etc., should be used. The activation function of last layer should be linear (or None). Similarly, `accuracy` is not a good metric for a regression case. The ones mentioned for loss can be used as metrics as well. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Predicting real estate prices needs a regression deep learninng model.
so the problem in that code is
1- in the output layer you're using 'sigmoid' function, change it to 'linear'
2- change the loss to mean absolute error or mean squarred error
3- change the metrics too to mae or mse
4-probably add more epochs, a neural network regression probably needs way more epochs to learn
Try those changes they should fix the problems

Answer (score 0):

**1. Output Layer Activation Function:**

You are using 'sigmoid' activation in the output layer. This activation function is typically used for binary classification problems, where the output represents probabilities of belonging to one of two classes. For predicting real estate prices, you should not use a sigmoid activation in the output layer. Instead, use a linear activation function or no activation function at all if you want to predict a continuous value (regression).

python code

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation=None))
```

**2. Loss Function:**

Since this is a regression problem (predicting real estate prices), you should use an appropriate loss function for regression, such as Mean Squared Error (MSE) or Mean Absolute Error (MAE). Replace 'binary_crossentropy' with 'mean_squared_error' for regression.

python code

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
```

**3. Evaluation Metric:**

When working with regression tasks, you should evaluate your model using regression metrics such as Mean Absolute Error (MAE), Mean Squared Error (MSE), or R-squared (R2), rather than accuracy, which is used for classification tasks. After training, calculate and print these metrics to assess your model's performance on the test set.

python code

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
mae = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred)

print("Mean Squared Error:", mse)
print("Mean Absolute Error:", mae)
```

**4. Model Complexity:**

The architecture of your neural network might need adjustment. Consider experimenting with different numbers of hidden layers and units to find the architecture that works best for your dataset. You can also try adding dropout layers to prevent overfitting.

**5. Data Preprocessing:**

Ensure that your data is properly preprocessed, scaled, and normalized if necessary. Incorrect data preprocessing can affect model performance significantly.

**6. Training Data:**
Make sure you have enough high-quality training data for your model. A small or noisy dataset can lead to poor performance.

Here's an updated example of how you can modify your code:

python code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error

# Create and compile the model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=6, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=6, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation=None)  # Linear activation for regression
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

# Train the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=100)

# Evaluate the model
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
mae = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred)

print("Mean Squared Error:", mse)
print("Mean Absolute Error:", mae)
```

By making these changes, you should be on the right track to building a regression model for predicting real estate prices. Adjust the model architecture and hyperparameters as needed to improve performance further.